# Calculation errors not returning correct values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following scrip and the beginning calculation is returning the same value it appears it is not following the grouping. I am returning 27 for every school. All 4 calculations are doing the same. When I query the data manually to check the values it return the correct data. It must be the way I am doing my calculation. It is to be counting the number of students and each proficiency level by grade. Any suggestions. You guy are great.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
 t.descript,
 t.schoolc AS School,
-- s.ident AS StdID,
--ze.descript,
  st.grdlvl,
 -- st.takendt, 
 --CASE td.subtestc WHEN 'LI' THEN 'CELDT Listening' WHEN 'RD' THEN 'CELDT Reading' WHEN 'SP' THEN 'CELDT Speaking' WHEN 'WR' THEN 'CELDT Writing' WHEN
 --               'TO' THEN 'CELDT Overall' ELSE '' END AS ELDassessment, 
 CASE st.testscore WHEN '1' THEN 'BE' WHEN '2' THEN ' EI' WHEN '3' THEN 'IN' WHEN '4' THEN 'EA' WHEN '5' THEN 'AD' ELSE '' END AS ProfLevel,

 sum (CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Beginning],
 sum((CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS [Early Intermediate],
 SUM(CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Intermediate],
 SUM(CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('4') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Early Advanced],
 SUM(CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('5') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Advanced]


FROM            dbo.stustat AS s INNER JOIN
                         dbo.track AS t ON s.trkuniq = t.trkuniq  INNER JOIN
                         dbo.stutests AS st ON s.suniq = st.suniq INNER JOIN
                         dbo.xstutests AS xst INNER JOIN
                         dbo.codeassoc AS ca3 ON xst.scrsource = ca3.zcode ON st.ststuniq = xst.ststuniq INNER JOIN
                         dbo.testval AS tv INNER JOIN
                         dbo.testdef AS td INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ztest AS zt INNER JOIN
                         dbo.codeassoc AS ca1 ON zt.testc = ca1.zcode ON td.testc = zt.testc INNER JOIN
                         dbo.zsubtest AS zst ON td.subtestc = zst.subtestc AND td.testc = zst.testc ON td.testuniq = tv.testuniq INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ztscrtyp AS ztscr INNER JOIN
                         dbo.codeassoc AS ca2 ON ztscr.tscrtypc = ca2.zcode ON tv.tscrtypc = ztscr.tscrtypc ON st.testuniq = tv.testuniq AND st.tscrtypc = tv.tscrtypc 
                        INNER JOIN studemo sd ON s.ident=sd.ident 
                        INNER JOIN dbo.zethnic ze ON sd.ethnicc=ze.ethnicc
WHERE        
--(st.takendt >= '2013-07-01') 
 (tv.tscrtypc = 'A') 
AND (td.subtestc IN ( 'TO'))
--AND (t.schoolc IN ('32'))
   AND  t.trkuniq NOT  BETWEEN '1'AND '1000066'
  AND t.trkuniq NOT BETWEEN  '1000134' AND '1000156'
 -- AND grdlvl ='0'
  --AND (st.testscore) IN ('1')

    GROUP BY  
     t.descript,
     td.subtestc,
     st.testscore,
 t.schoolc ,
 s.ident ,
--ze.descript,
  st.grdlvl
 -- st.takendt

  ORDER BY  t.descript, t.schoolc,st.grdlvl
```

Comment: You have an aggregate on testscore but you also have it in your group by. You probably need to look at MAX(testscore) in your case expression and drop it from the group by.

Comment: Are we supposed to know **which** calculation is giving wrong values?, and what does "wrong values" mean here?

Comment: sorry about that  all calcs are giving wrong data. they are returning mostly the same values 27 or 54 . When checking the raw data it should of been 5

Comment: You are joining a zillion tables together and then using an aggregation.  This usually means that you are joining along different dimensions, creating a small cartesian product, unexpectedly.  With no sample data or data layouts, it is hard to say much beyond that.

Comment: Noting again your lack of marking answers.  Please be sure to mark answers John.  This site works because for those that ask questions and those that give answers there is a mutual benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Your ON Clauses in your joins are all over the place I have only guessed below and have tried to fix most of them see below

You have used Two `ON` clauses in joins if you have more than one condition in JOIN's ON clause, you should use `AND` to mentioned 2nd , 3rd conditions but you do not use `ON` more than Once to specify multiple conditions in your ON clause.

For massive queries like this one, proper Indentation makes much easier to write/debug//amend code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                 t.descript
                ,t.schoolc AS School
              --,s.ident AS StdID
              --,ze.descript
                ,st.grdlvl
              --,st.takendt 
              --,CASE td.subtestc WHEN 'LI' THEN 'CELDT Listening' 
                                 --WHEN 'RD' THEN 'CELDT Reading' 
                                 --WHEN 'SP' THEN 'CELDT Speaking' 
                                 --WHEN 'WR' THEN 'CELDT Writing' 
                                 --WHEN 'TO' THEN 'CELDT Overall' ELSE '' END AS ELDassessment 
              --,CASE st.testscore WHEN '1' THEN 'BE' 
                                   --WHEN '2' THEN ' EI' 
                                   --WHEN '3' THEN 'IN' 
                                   --WHEN '4' THEN 'EA' 
                                   --WHEN '5' THEN 'AD' ELSE '' END AS ProfLevel
                ,sum (CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Beginning]
                ,sum((CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS [Early Intermediate]
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('3') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Intermediate]
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('4') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Early Advanced]
                ,SUM(CASE WHEN (st.testscore) IN ('5') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Advanced]

FROM dbo.stustat AS s 
INNER JOIN dbo.track AS t       ON s.trkuniq = t.trkuniq  
INNER JOIN dbo.stutests AS st   ON s.suniq = st.suniq 
INNER JOIN dbo.xstutests AS xst ON st.ststuniq = xst.ststuniq 
INNER JOIN dbo.codeassoc AS ca3 ON xst.scrsource = ca3.zcode 
INNER JOIN dbo.testval AS tv    ON st.testuniq = tv.testuniq AND st.tscrtypc = tv.tscrtypc
INNER JOIN dbo.testdef AS td    ON td.testuniq = tv.testuniq 
INNER JOIN dbo.ztest AS zt      ON td.testc = zt.testc
INNER JOIN dbo.codeassoc AS ca1 ON zt.testc = ca1.zcode  
INNER JOIN dbo.zsubtest AS zst  ON td.subtestc = zst.subtestc AND td.testc = zst.testc 
INNER JOIN dbo.ztscrtyp AS ztscr ON tv.tscrtypc = ztscr.tscrtypc 
INNER JOIN dbo.codeassoc AS ca2 ON ztscr.tscrtypc = ca2.zcode  
INNER JOIN studemo sd           ON s.ident=sd.ident 
INNER JOIN dbo.zethnic ze       ON sd.ethnicc=ze.ethnicc
WHERE  (tv.tscrtypc = 'A')      
  AND (td.subtestc IN ( 'TO'))
  AND  t.trkuniq NOT  BETWEEN '1'AND '1000066'
  AND t.trkuniq NOT BETWEEN  '1000134' AND '1000156'
 -- AND (st.takendt >= '2013-07-01') AND (t.schoolc IN ('32')) 
 -- AND grdlvl ='0'  AND (st.testscore) IN ('1')
GROUP BY  t.descript
        ,t.schoolc
      --,s.ident 
      --,ze.descript
        ,st.grdlvl
ORDER BY  t.descript, t.schoolc,st.grdlvl
```